# DFT coefficients are totally different from FFT

Tags: python, fft, dft

I found the Fourier Transform coefficients using the following formula:

[image]

I used the following values as a signal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import tau
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec
import numpy as np

signal_x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2])
signal_y = np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3])

plt.plot(signal_x, signal_y)
```

[image]

After that I found the coefficients by transcribing the DFT formula of complex numbers in python

[image]

```
new_x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(signal_x))

# LINEAR INTERPOLATION
def f(t, new_x, x, y):
    return np.interp(t, new_x, np.array(x) + 1j*np.array(y))

# DFT Complex Number
qt_coeff = 5
coeffs = []
for n in range(-qt_coeff, qt_coeff): # -5 +4 = 10 coeffs
    coef = 1/tau * quad_vec(lambda t: f(t, new_x, signal_x, signal_y)*np.exp(t*1j*n), 0, tau)[0]
    coeffs.append(coef)

coeffs = np.array(coeffs)

print(coeffs)

# [ 0.04353136+0.02109635j  0.04473849+0.07575828j  0.09004453-0.00688048j
#  -0.0256607 +0.13901032j -0.19044464+0.17837592j  3.61111111+4.11111111j
#  -1.37786713-0.37885172j -0.17198653+0.00530144j -0.16603542-0.06911041j
#  -0.11103156-0.05656161j]
```

But when using the FFT to gain speed the values of the coefficients are totally different.

```
# FFT - Fast Fourier transform
signal_complex = signal_x + 1j*signal_y
coeffs_fft = np.fft.fft(signal_complex)
print(coeffs_fft)

#[ 3.40000000e+01+41.j -3.31676888e+00 +1.j -1.00000000e+00 +1.j
#  9.25221011e-01 +1.j -1.00000000e+00 +1.j -4.44089210e-16 +1.j
# -1.00000000e+00 +1.j -1.98094910e+00 +1.j -1.00000000e+00 +1.j
# -1.56275030e+01 +1.j]
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, to be able to use the FFT correctly?

Comment: That's not the DFT formula. Here's what you should compute: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition

Comment: How do I find the coefficients using fft?

Comment: What do you mean? You did that already: `coeffs_fft = np.fft.fft(signal_complex)`.

Comment: Yes, but the values ​​are quite different between `coeffs` and `coeffs_fft`

Comment: Yes, because `coeffs` is something different. It is not the DFT, which would produce the same values (up to rounding errors) as the FFT, because the FFT is just an efficient algorithm to compute the DFT. I don't know what your equation is, it is related somehow to the continuous domain Fourier transform, but evaluated only on a limited domain. I don't know where you got it from.

Comment: I took it from this site `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform` in the `Fourier transform for functions that are zero outside an interval`

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But the Fourier Transform (FT) and the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) are different things. The FFT computes the DFT, not the FT.